# Format a string with a C# code before putting it into a webgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on an asp.net MVC 3 application.

I have a C# function that takes a string as an input, formats it and then returns the formatted string.

I have a .cshtml file where I fill data in a webgrid.

When filling the data in the webgrid, I want to format it first through a C# function and then fill the results.

In asp.net I can simply use the code behind to do it. but I am new to MVC 3 so any suggestions on how to do it is greatly appreciated.

I heard it should be done in the action. can you help me on how to do that?

the C# function look like this

```
public string FormatString (string input)
{
    // I Format the string and return it
}
```

the webgrid look like this

```
<div id="GridDiv">
@grid.GetHtml(
        htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
        tableStyle: "grid",
        headerStyle: "header",
        rowStyle: "row",
        footerStyle: "footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Name", "Name", style: "Centered", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("Address", "Address", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("City", "City", canSort: true),
            grid.Column("PhoneNumber", "Phone Number", style: "Centered"),
        ))
```

I want to format the Name, Address, City, and PhoneNumber

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, personally I have never used the Grid helper, but I assume this would be the general direction.
Let's say the Name/Phone/City/Address are properties of a Person class.

Build an appropriate view model

```
public sealed class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Address {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}

    public MyViewModel(Person person)
    {
        FillViewModel(person); // either copy the given properties by hand, use Automapper, or write your own simple (although quite general) mapping method using reflection
        Address = FormatString(Address);
        City = FormatString(City);
        PhoneNumber = FormatString(PhoneNumber);
    }
    public MyViewModel()
    { 
    }
}
```

Use it in controller action

```
public ActionResult ShowGrid(int personId)
{
    var person = SomeKindOfDatabaseAccess.GetPerson(personId);
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel(person);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

And then use this model on your page, so when you pass PhoneNumber, City and Address to the grid in the view, you'll have them pre-formatted.

**EDIT: Regarding 'where to put the FormatString method'**

As I see it, you can put it in the 'Person' model class if you're going to use it in the Person-related business only:

(If the Person class is generated from e.g. EF, you can do it in a different file so it looks neat, like below)

```
public sealed partial class Person
{
     public string FormatString(string input)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

or

```
public sealed partial class Person
{
     public static string FormatString(string input)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

or if you're feeling fancy (or - more practically -  you're going to use it in any other situation for string formatting), you can define the method as a string extension for convenience:

```
public static class Extensions
{
     public static string FormatString(this string input)
     {
         ...
     }
}
```

And then: `PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.FormatString();`

Comment: Thank you for your answer I am trying it. one question: Where do I put the FormatString() function implementation? in the model class?

Comment: Well, that mainly depends what you'd use it for, you can put it in the model class as a regular method, you can even make it plain static or a string extension method. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that thing in Model itself. In get property of the (Name, Address, City, and PhoneNumber) you can format the string. And if you are using this property anywhere else than you can add new properties for all 4 columns (Name, Address, City, and PhoneNumber) and in get property set the format and bind this columns to grid.

For example

```
private string temp;
public string Temp { get { return string.Format("Hi {0}",this.temp);} set{}}
```

Instead of string.Format you can call your defined function also.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to create a ViewModel or custom function, and simply want to do some formatting in the WebGrid "on-the-fly", you could use the following syntax:

```
<div id="GridDiv">
@grid.GetHtml(
    htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" },
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "header",
    rowStyle: "row",
    footerStyle: "footer",
    alternatingRowStyle: "altRow",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Name", "Name", style: "Centered", canSort: true),
        grid.Column("Scheduled", header: "Scheduled", 
            format: @<text>@(String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm}",item.DateScheduled ?? "Unscheduled"))</text>),
    ))
</div>
```

The Scheduled column (of type `DateTime?`) will be displayed in the given format, or display the "Unscheduled" special value if it is `null`.